# A model that belongs_to two models or a polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, models

I have three models

1. User
2. Product
3. Order

A `user` who submits `product`s and other users can `order` that product.

Now I want to implement another model `payment`, where I as an admin pay the user.

**Question**
I am confused about what kind of association should i create between `user`, `order` and `payment`?

This is what I currently have : 
in `app/models/user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :products_selling,  class_name: 'Product'
  has_many :orders_received, class_name: 'Order', through: :products_selling, source: :orders

  has_many :orders_made, class_name: 'Order'
  has_many :products_ordering,  class_name: 'Product', through: :orders_made, source: :product

  has_one :payment, class_name: 'Payment', through: :orders_received
```

and in `app/models/order.rb`

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :buyer, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
    has_one :seller, class_name: 'User', through: :product

    has_one :payment, through: :seller
```

and in `app/models/payment.rb`

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :order
```

I am not sure what association should be used, I have been reading and there are examples using `polymorphic: :true` but they were all with `has_many`, where as in my case one order corresponds to one payment.

Comment: is this a candidate for self-joins: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Associations**

[**Polymorphic associations**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) basically allow you to use a single table to manage multiple associations:

[image]

So if you wanted to link `multiple` tables to a `single` table, it will essentially create a `pseudo` object, which can be associated with different data types. We typically use polymorphic associations with tables which can be used by multiple models, examples including `images`, `errors`, `posts` etc:

[image]

In regards to relating polymorphic associations to `has_many` / `has_one`, I'm not entirely sure (I can research if you want)

--

**Fix**

In your case, I would do this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :orders
  has_many :purchases, class_name: 'Order', foreign_key: "buyer_id"

  has_many :products
  has_many :bought,  class_name: 'Product', through: :purchases

end

#app/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :product
   has_one :payment
end

#app/models/payment.rb
Class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields - id | user_id | order_id | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :order #-> user pays for order
   belongs_to :user #-> user making the payment
end
```

This will allow you to create `payments` for each `order` - which is *really* what payments are for, right? (You pay for the `order`, not the `product`)

Comment: Thanks @Rich, for the elaborate answer. Looks like the `polymorphic` association is not well suited for this scenario. Also, seems like I was on the right track. Just to make the question more clear (not sure if this changes the answer), users buy products posted by other users. When a user places that order, the money is transferred to the admin's account, and then  this admin transfers all the sellers(users) their money after taking his cut. With this being said, is the `belongs_to :user` necessary in 'app/models/payment.rb' as it is always one admin who makes payments to the sellers.